# How to retrieve PDF file attached to an XML file - Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, pdf

I have an XML file that presents a .pdf attached (inside of it).

I would like to extract that file using python.

-----

Here xml reference where pdf file is stored in the xml:

`<Allegati>`

`<NomeAttachment>20230531_000203490_FTM.pdf</NomeAttachment>`

`<AlgoritmoCompressione>ZIP</AlgoritmoCompressione>`

`<FormatoAttachment>PDF</FormatoAttachment>`

`<DescrizioneAttachment>DOCUMENTO ALLEGATO</DescrizioneAttachment>`

`<Attachment>UEs...QAH </Attachment>`

`</Allegati>`

-----

Could someone please help me?

I tried parsing xml and reading pdf part with the following code:

```
with open(path, 'r') as file_xml:
    xml_data = file_xml.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, 'html.parser')

with open(soup.attachment, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

But i get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10552\144676354.py in <module>
----> 1 with open(soup.attachment, 'wb') as f:
      2     f.write(response.content)

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Tag
```

Answer (score 0):

The embeded payload is `UEs...QAH` which shows it is as binary PK...� hence is a zip file encoded for XML as Base64 text.

Thus

- "simply" `save` the payload as a text file and `decode` into a `binary.zip`
- THEN `Tar -xf binary.zip` can extract the encoded binary.pdf.

I dont python so you need a good example as to how to selectively delete head and tail before and after the payload.

### Luckily

This Italian format is very well known
**HOWEVER there was a structure change dated 2022-10-01**
[*Electronic invoicing to the Public Administration Exchange System*](https://www.fatturapa.gov.it/it/index.html)

Technical details for programmer/developers are at https://www.fatturapa.gov.it/it/norme-e-regole/documentazione-fattura-elettronica/formato-fatturapa/

and there is a Library specifically for Python Extraction at https://github.com/alexlab2017/xtract_attachment
but that predates the change mentioned above so may need adjustment.

> Utility to extract the attachment(s) from an "xml" file following the Italian "Fattura Elettronica" format.